# Static initialization of mtx_t using threads.h

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, c11

`threads.h` supports only dynamic mutex initialization with [mtx_init()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/mtx_init).

Aparently there isn't any info on the internet regarding threads.h apart from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread.( I would really like to know if there is something more)

Does anyone know how is `struct mtx_t` in `threads.h` implemented?
I would like to init the mutex statically like in pthreads (  PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER ), to avoid calling initialization function every time at the start of the program.

Comment: threads.h is just the interface, various implementation might implement a mutex in very different ways as long as it behaves like C11 requires.

Comment: BTW, the newest POSIX standard lifted the restriction of the initializer only to be used in a static context. It is now valid for any storage class, in particular `auto` variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ability of the C11 threads.h to initialize a mutex without calling mtx_init()

threads.h is implemented differently on different platforms - so knowing the implementation detail of how a mtx_t actually look like would't be of much use, you'd be just as well off using the native thread api if it exists, such as pthreads which does provide this ability.

Comment: So two threads initializing at the same time might break the mtx, since there is no way to mtx_lock the actual mtx_init. The only way to do it is to call init at the start before even creating threads.

Comment: @self if the 2 threads need to initialize the same mutex, yes. Although in such a case the mutex would normally be a globabl variable for it to make sense to have 2 threads initialize the same mutex - which one might as well initialize before creating those threads. There's one other possibility, which is to use the `call_once()` function to call another function which initializes the mutex in a race free way that ensures the function is called only once.

Comment: @nos, C11 threads have some more possibilities to do initialization. `atomic_flag` or other `_Atomic` as an auxiliary data would also be a possibility to cope with this regrettable lack of a static initializer. These (the atomics) provide such static initializers.

Comment: @JensGustedt [call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once) might work to init mutexes but i think it might not prevent an immediate call to uninitialized mutex in some threads.

Comment: @self That's why you have to rewrite that code to either use call_once() or call mtx_init() that you run before that code, e.g. in main() before starting the threads.

Comment: @JensGustedt But if going with call_once, couldn't another thread hit an uninit mutex when one thread is in call_once?

Comment: call_once() synchronized that, as long as all threads perform the call_once() to initialize the mutex you should be good. (you would get the problem you describe if you use a naive approach with atmomic_flag or _Atomic though)